# CORS issue between React/Redux frontend and Node.js backend

Tags: javascript, cors

The React app is on port 3000 and my server is on port 4000.
From my Redux action i'm calling this route

```
 axios.get("localhost:4000/auth/user", config) 
      .then(res => dispatch({
          type: USER_LOADED,
          payload: res.data
      }))
```

And get this error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:4000/auth/user' from origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https.

Even though I already added these CORS settings to the server :

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With')

  next()
})
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost:4000/auth/user` is not a valid URL. The browser is interpreting the `localhost:` as the scheme, hence the error message about the scheme:

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

You should be using `http://localhost:4000/auth/user` as your URL.

Answer (score 0):

### As per standards

You need to add CORS on server side of Node.js Code:

### npm - CORS

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

Read more: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/#documentation). It's a server proxy that adds CORS headers to your requests(I would advise against this in production because it slows down response times).

The most optimal way to solve this is to create your own proxy like so

```js
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});

app.get('/route', (req, res) => {
  request(
    { url: 'https://www.example.com' },
    (error, response, body) => {
      if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: err.message });
      }

      res.json(JSON.parse(body));
    }
  )
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on ${PORT}`));
```